# why bintrayUpload Could not create version '0.1' ? HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, gradle, version, bintray

what is problem with my version ?

**bintray.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

version = '0.1'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

bintray{
    user = 'user_name'
    key = 'apikey'

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'notification-handler'
        desc = 'first initiate'
        websiteUrl = 'myWebsiteUrl'
        vcsUrl = 'MyVcsUrl'
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
        publicDownloadNumbers = true
    }
}
```

**Error**

> Information:Gradle tasks [bintrayUpload]
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':parham-notification-handler:bintrayUpload'.
>
> ***Could not create version '0.1': HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized*** [message:This resource requires authentication]
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Try change bintray.user and bintray.key to these lines:

```
user  = property('user')
key   = property('key')
```

After run the following command:

```
gradle -Puser=YOUR_BINTRAY_USERNAME -Pkey=YOUR_BINTRAY_API_KEY bintrayUpload --info
```

You can get your Bintray API_KEY through the edit bintray profile page under "API Key" tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) tutorial and [this](https://github.com/robohorse/gpversionchecker/blob/master/gpversionchecker/build.gradle) configuration as example. "bintray.user" and "bintray.apikey" located in local.properties file

Comment: I used this

[link](https://antoniocappiello.com/2015/11/11/publish-your-library-to-jcenter-in-3-steps/)

could be acceptable ?

Comment: yes, why not (i have no time to read it) :) I added url to tutorial, that i used to upload my library - it worked for me many times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (that I used `local.properites`), *I had declared variable values as strings (in quotes).*

```
bintray.user='user'
bintray.apikey='sdasasfsrefsfercfsfV'
```

Which is not correct. So I remoted the quotes.

```
bintray.user=user
bintray.apikey=sdasasfsre
```